# Swift 3.0 Conversion UITableView Not Calling Methods In UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I have just converted from swift 2.2 to 3.0 My project worked before and since the conversion data isn't loading into the UITableView. The `deviceTableView` set as a delegate. I've searched numerous posts and everything I've tried hasn't seemed to work. When setting a breakpoint on any of the `func tableView(` the program never breaks. So the functions are never being called.

```
  import UIKit
    class DeviceViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, TransferTime {


      @IBOutlet weak var timerview: UIProgressView!

   @IBOutlet weak var deviceTableView: UITableView!

    let singleton = EmailSingleton.sharedInstance
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    deviceTableView.delegate = self

}

func progressHasChanged(_ progressData: Float){

    timerview.setProgress(progressData, animated: true)
}
func declareGameStatus(_ gameStatus: Bool) {
    if gameStatus == true || gameStatus == false {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return singleton.LDCE.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtindexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = deviceTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "email") as! EmailTableViewCell
    let person = singleton.LDCE[cellForRowAtindexPath.row]
    cell.emailText.text = person


    return cell
}

@IBAction func deleteButtonIsPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let indexPaths = deviceTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows! as? [IndexPath] {
        for indexPath in indexPaths {

            singleton.LDCE.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        deviceTableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }
}

@IBAction func backbutton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

The UITableView should be displaying the text from singleton.

Comment: You never set the table view `dataSource`. And most of the method signatures have changed in Swift 3.

Comment: I didn't think I would need the datasource since I'm using a singleton to populate the list

Comment: @HoneyBadger If you doesn't set datasource of tableView then it will never call `numberOfRowIn section` and `cellForRowAt indexPath` methods.

Comment: I just fixed it, thank you @ Nirav D and @rmaddy. For some reason I thought you would only use datasource with core data. My apologies, I'm still new to swift.